# Improving layout of state machine in graphviz

Tags: graph, graphviz, dot

I'm new to graphviz and could use a little help with improving layout.

For my uni class I have to draw a graph for a finite state machine. Code follows:

```
digraph fsm{
    //rankdir=LR;   //left-right orientation

    node[shape=Mrecord]
    S00[label="{S0|1111111111}"];
    S01[label="{S1|0110010101}"];
    S02[label="{S2|1000010110}"];
    S03[label="{S3|1000010110}"];
    S04[label="{S4|0100010101}"];
    S05[label="{S5|0010110101}"];
    S06[label="{S6|0011001001}"];
    S07[label="{S7|0011001001}"];
    S08[label="{S8|0010100101}"];
    S09[label="{S9|0100100000}"];
    S10[label="{S10|0100100000}"];
    S11[label="{S11|0000000000}"];
    S12[label="{S12|0100100000}"];
    //S0
    S00 -> S00[label="t<8s"];
    S00 -> S01[label="t>8s"];
    S00 -> S09[label="NM"];
    //S1
    S01 -> S01[label="t<1s"];
    S01 -> S02[label="t>1s"];
    S01 -> S09[label="NM"];
    //S2
    S02 -> S02[label="t<6s"];
    S02 -> S03[label="t>6s"];
    S02 -> S09[label="NM"];
    //S3
    S03 -> S03[label="t<7s"];
    S03 -> S04[label="t>7s OR I_NS OR I_HS-F"];
    S03 -> S09[label="NM"];
    //S4
    S04 -> S04[label="t<1s"];
    S04 -> S05[label="t>1s"];
    S04 -> S09[label="NM"];
    //S5
    S05 -> S05[label="t<1s"];
    S05 -> S06[label="t>1s"];
    S05 -> S09[label="NM"];
    //S6
    S06 -> S06[label="t<2s"];
    S06 -> S07[label="t>2s"];
    S06 -> S09[label="NM"];
    //S7
    S07 -> S07[label="t<4s"];
    S07 -> S08[label="t>4s OR I_HS OR I_NS-F"];
    S07 -> S09[label="NM"];
    //S8
    S08 -> S08[label="t<1s"];
    S08 -> S01[label="t>1s"];
    S08 -> S09[label="NM"];
    //S9
    S09 -> S09[label="t<1.5s"];
    S09 -> S10[label="t>1.5s"];
    //S10
    S10 -> S10[label="t<0.5s"];
    S10 -> S11[label="t>0.5s"];
    S10 -> S12[label="t>0.5s"];
    //S11
    S11 -> S11[label="t<0.5s"];
    S11 -> S10[label="t>0.5s"];
    S11 -> S12[label="t>0.5s"];
    //S12
    S12 -> S12[label="t<1.5s"];
    S12 -> S00[label="t>1.5s"];
}
```

Output is this:
[image: Graph]

So yes, it works. But it is very ugly.

Any advice on how to improve the layout?

What bothers me most is the little distance between edges and text, overlapping of edges and the curves in the edges from S4-S7 to S9.

Any input is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the attribute for splines to `splines=ortho` and grouping the nodes `[S1:S8]` into a subgraph (ex: `subgraph SGn { (Sxx defs in here) }`) will take you a long way toward cleaning up your layout.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I turned the cluttered graph in for the course and never had to use graphviz afterwards